# Convert $(\log n)^n$ to the form $n^x$ for some $x$

Tags: logarithms

How do I convert ${\log n}^n$ to the form $n^x$, for some $x$? I'd like to compare the big-O runtime of $(\log n)^n$ to $n^{\log n}$ directly. Intuitively, $(\log n)^n$ grows faster since the exponent grows faster but I'm not sure how to prove the result directly. Any tips or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Take $\log$ of both sides to get $x=\frac{n\log\log n}{\log n}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you want to write

$$(\log n)^n = n^x$$

If you take logarithm of both sides:

\begin{align*} \log \left( \log n \right)^n &= \log(n^x) \\ n \log(\log n) &= x \log n \\ x &=\frac{n \log (\log n)}{\log n}\end{align*}

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Thank you @wythagoras for correcting the important omission of $n$ in the numerator.

Comment: Please thank @Simpson17866 instead. I merely approved and improved his edit by fixing a little formatting.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this $(\ln n)^n = e^{n\ln\ln n}$ and $n^{\ln n} = e^{\ln n\ln n}$. 
Is it helpful?

Comment: Maybe easier to parse:  $e^{n (\log\log n)}$ vs. $e^{(\log n)^2}$.

Comment: I need the answer to have base $n$.

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite it as following:

$$\log(n)^n = (n^{\log_n (\log (n))})^n = n^{n \log_n( \log(n))} = n^{\frac{n \log (\log (n))}{\log(n)}}$$